# QProcess and firefox

Tags: c++, qt, firefox, qprocess

I have an issues trying to launch firefox through QProcess.
Here is the function I used to launch commands (such as firefox, mkdir, ...)

```
double launch_nowait(string cmd, bool display) {
    string command_name = "";
    string command_param = "";
    bool first_space = false;
    for (int p = 0; p < cmd.size(); p++) {
        if (!first_space && cmd[p] == ' ') first_space = true;
        else {
            if (!first_space)   command_name += cmd[p];
            else                command_param += cmd[p];
        }
    }
    cout << "NOWAIT [" << command_name << "][" << command_param << "]" << endl;
    QProcess* process;
    //process->setWorkingDirectory(".");
    //process->waitForFinished();
    process->start(QString::fromStdString(command_name), QStringList() << QString::fromStdString(command_param));
    return 0;
}
```

I tried several things such as :

- removing parameters,
- changing the navigator to chrome
- adding a wait
- setting the working directory

But it always ends with a seg fault.

The strange thing is that when I use this function to create a directory it works fine.

Thanks for your help,

Comment: Where do you allocate `process`?  The code, as posted, will display undefined behaviour.

Comment: arf ... thanks it must be the problem